# Unable to resolve convert ion of iPhone xib to ipad xib

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5, xcode4.2

Kindly point out if i have missed something?
I have a project with type 'universe'. it works fine for iPhone.

I applied  the following steps to get the iPad version.

```
1)  duplicate the .xib.
2) Open source Code mode { xib file} and do the followings.
    a) changed <archive type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="8.00">
       to
       <archive type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.iPad.XIB" version="8.00">

b) replaced IBCocoaTouchFramework  with IBIPadFramework
c) changed the resolution of IBUIView to 
        <string key="NSFrame">{{0, 20}, {768, 1024}}</string>
```

Now, when i execute, i still see the output as if iPhone xib is embedded into the iPad view?.

am i missing anything ? Kindly point out the mistake i am doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some how got it fixed by changing the co-ordination of main view.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the coordinates of all the controls used within that class also.

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem ,
 in my case, **reopened Xib from FolderOption** 
and deleted the ~iPad.XIb file
 duplicated again, this time replaced whole **archive type** instead of adding .iPad, there should **not be any space between InterfaceBuilder3 and CocoaTouch**